# Polymer: Global/document level styling module

Tags: html, css, import, polymer, global

How do I declare a global or document level styling module for Polymer? Polymer's App Toolbox starter-kit places document styles inline in the `index.html` file:

```
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
  }
</style>
```

However, I'd like to separate this into a module.

The starter-kit template also contains a `shared-styles.html` module that can be imported into each module to take effect, but this approach means repeating in `import` directive in every module.

Answer (score 0):

### >= 1.7

See: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/2016-10-03-1.7-release (thanks Tony19)

To contextualise, the following module contains document level styling:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<style is="custom-style">

    /* Declare document level styling, variables and mixins here */
    html {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-color: #eeeeee;

        --example-css-var: 1rem;

        --example-css-mixin: {
            width: 100%;
        };
    }

</style>
```

This module would then be included within the `head` tags of the required page/app entry point. I.e:

```
<link rel="import" href="/src/styles/document-styles.html">
```

Note that global styling (i.e. styles that 'pierce' web components through their API) needs to be in the form of a CSS variable or mixin, and would be placed within `html`.

### < 1.7

See: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-style

To contextualise, the following module contains document level styling:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<style is="custom-style">

    /* Declare document level styling */
    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
    }

    /* Declare document level variables and mixins here */
    :root {
        --example-css-var: 1rem;

        --example-css-mixin: {
            width: 100%;
        };
    }

</style>
```

This module would then be included within the `head` tags of the required page/app entry point. I.e:

```
<link rel="import" href="/src/styles/document-styles.html">
```

Note that global styling (i.e. styles that 'pierce' web components through their API) needs to be in the form of a CSS variable or mixin, and would be placed within `:root`.

Comment: fyi, `:root` is deprecated for `html`

Comment: Thanks Tony19. I can't find where this is documented though? Do you have a link to this? Thanks

Comment: What if you load multiple style modules, that all define some overlapping `html` level custom properties: is the winning rule decided by JS module loading order?